# Absolute continuity on measure spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Take $M_F(\mathbb{N})$ the space of finite measures in $\mathbb{N}$ endowed with its weak topology. Define $F$ such that $$  M_F(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow M_F(\mathbb{N})$$
$$\ \mu \mapsto F(\mu)$$
Is it true that if $F(\mu)$ is absolutely continuous (in the sense of measures ie $F(\mu) << \mu$) then $F$ is continuous in $\mu$? In the weak topology? In a stronger topology?

Edit: As shown by @MaoWao, it is usually not true in the case of domination, extending the question to **equivalence**. Is $F$ continuous when $F(\mu) << \mu$ and $ \mu << F(\mu)$

Comment: How is $F(\mu)$ defined?

Comment: The only information we have is that $\mu(A) = 0$ implies $F(\mu)(A) = 0$ 
We can extend to the case where it is actually an equivalence $ \mu(A) = 0 \iff F(\mu)(A) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Usually not. Take any non-zero finite measure $\mu_0$ on $\mathbb N$ and define $F(\mu)=0$ if $\mu\neq\mu_0$ and $F(\mu_0)=\mu_0$. As long as $\mu_0$ is not an isolated point and the topology is Hausdorff, this map is not continuous at $\mu_0$. But of course $F(\mu_0)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu_0$.

Comment: Thank you! What if we make it an equivalence condition instead of a dominance one like $F(\mu) = 0 \iff \mu=0$ ?